# How to remove xml encoding from beautiful soup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I would like to know how i can remove the encoding automatically created by prettify in BeautifulSoup. Example:

```
tree='''<A attribute1="1" attribute2="2">
 <B>
  <C/>
 </B>
</A>'''
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
root = Soup(tree, 'lxml-xml')
print root.prettify().replace('\n', '')
```

The output looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><A attribute1="1" attribute2="2"> <B>  <C/> </B></A>
```

I would like simply:

```
<A attribute1="1" attribute2="2"> <B>  <C/> </B></A>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about it:

The first, call `root.decode_contents()`, which will give you a non-prettified content-only output.

Or prettify each chunk in contents separately and then join them. Like this: `'\n'.join(x.prettify() for x in root.contents)`.